# Trying to generate 100 boxes but only 2 boxes are displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm only using javascript, html, and css to generate 100 boxes in any random position, this works by using the div with the id container in the html file and then using the javascript file to generate the boxes through a loop making a div for each box then appending it to the container, but the problem is I can see two boxes appearing on screen? here is my code below:

```
//this is the javascript
function myFunction(){

      var container = document.getElementById("container");//o

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {//o
          var box = document.createElement("div");//o
           box.setAttribute("id", "box");
           
          container.appendChild(box);//o
          var bx = document.getElementById("box");

          var w=window.innerWidth;
          var h=window.innerHeight;

          bx.style.right = w * Math.random() + "px";
          bx.style.top = h * Math.random() + "px";


      }
  }
```

```
//here is the css
#box
{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;

}
```

```
//this is the html
<!DOCUTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
  
<link href = "box.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src = "box.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: `id`s should be unique

Comment: There's a reason it's called `getElementById` and not `getElementsById`

Answer (score 1):

## Don't get a reference for the box again from the DOM

```
    function myFunction(){

      var container = document.getElementById("container");//o

      for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {//o
          var box = document.createElement("div");//o
          box.setAttribute("id", "box");
           
          container.appendChild(box);//o
          // var bx = document.getElementById("box"); <--- this line is redundant

          var w=window.innerWidth;
          var h=window.innerHeight;

          box.style.right = w * Math.random() + "px";
          box.style.top = h * Math.random() + "px";


      }
   }
```

## ID's should be unique, instead use a class for each box

```
function myFunction(){

      var container = document.getElementById("container");//o

      for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {//o
          var box = document.createElement("div");//o
          box.classList.add("box");
           
          container.appendChild(box);//o

          var w=window.innerWidth;
          var h=window.innerHeight;

          box.style.right = w * Math.random() + "px";
          box.style.top = h * Math.random() + "px";


      }
  }
```

## So your code in the end becomes:

```js
function myFunction(){

      var container = document.getElementById("container");//o

      for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {//o
          var box = document.createElement("div");//o
          box.classList.add("box");
           
          container.appendChild(box);//o

          var w=window.innerWidth;
          var h=window.innerHeight;

          box.style.right = w * Math.random() + "px";
          box.style.top = h * Math.random() + "px";


      }
  }
```

```css
.box
{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">

<head>
  
<link href = "box.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src = "box.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **name** attribute and a **data-id** attribute to retrieve any elements with an unique id.

Construction:

```
let container = document.getElementById("container")
for(let count = 1; count < 100; ++count) {
    let box = document.createElement("DIV")
    box.setAttribute("name", "e")
    box.dataset.id = count

    container.appendChild(box)
}
```

HTML result :

```
<div name="e" data-id="1"></div>
<div name="e" data-id="2"></div>
<div name="e" data-id="3"></div>
<div name="e" data-id="4"></div>
```

Add a function to retrieve any element with the first occurence of a numbered id.

```
function getFormRef(name, id) {
    let d = document.getElementsByName(name)
    let x = Array.prototype.slice.call(d).filter(a => a.dataset.id == id)
    return x[0]
}

let first = getFormRef("e", 1)
```